# overriding start() method in multithreaded Java code

Tags: java, multithreading

In the following code snippet I am unable to understand how "Run method" is printed in the output. Since the start() method is overloaded, it will be called by main thread and no new thread will be created. Calling super.start() will call super class (Thread class) run method (which is empty) and will be executed as separate thread. It is not clear to me how run method of MyThread class is getting executed?
thank you

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Run method");
    }

    public void start () {
        super.start();
        System.out.println("Start Method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread thread1 = new MyThread();
        thread1.start();
        System.out.println("Main method");

    }
}
```

Comment: Just because you are invoking the parent's (ie. `super` class) method, it doesn't mean that the parent's `run()` is executed.  You are still within `MyThread` class so that's the class that will have its `run()` method invoked (after the `start()` method is finished)

Comment: *Calling super.start() will call super class (Thread class) run method (which is empty)* -- Nope, it will call the overriding method `MyThread.run()`, because of dynamic binding.